# Receiving a broadcast message in C#

Tags: c#, broadcast

I have tried a lot, but somehow there seems to be some problem with the code to receive a datagram that is broadcast by a remote host.

So could someone please provide me with the code to receive a broadcast message in C# using a UDP connection?

Comment: I think your question is answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746519/udp-receiving

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Network/ReceiveBroadcast.htm

```
/*
C# Network Programming 
by Richard Blum

Publisher: Sybex 
ISBN: 0782141765
*/
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

public class RecvBroadcst
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                      SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
      IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9050);
      sock.Bind(iep);
      EndPoint ep = (EndPoint)iep;
      Console.WriteLine("Ready to receive...");

      byte[] data = new byte[1024];
      int recv = sock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref ep);
      string stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
      Console.WriteLine("received: {0}  from: {1}",
                            stringData, ep.ToString());

      data = new byte[1024];
      recv = sock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref ep);
      stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
      Console.WriteLine("received: {0}  from: {1}",
                            stringData, ep.ToString());
      sock.Close();
   }
}
```