# can receive broadcast messages

Tags: c#, networking, udp, broadcast

I am trying to write code the receives broadcast messages coming from another app. using wireShark, I can see that they are sent to 255.255.255.255:300.

I tried the following code:

```
                IPEndPoint ServerEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 3000);
                Socket WinSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
                WinSocket.Bind(ServerEndPoint);
                byte[] data = new byte[10];
                Console.Write("Waiting for client");
                IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                EndPoint Remote = (EndPoint)(sender);
                int recv = WinSocket.ReceiveFrom(data, ref Remote);
                Console.WriteLine("Message received from {0}:", Remote.ToString());
                string str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
```

but when my app reached to the "bind" command there is an error message:
"Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted"

if I change the port there is no error but I catch nothing.

Please advice

Comment: The source and destination ports do not need to be the same. In fact, you should use source port `0` to allow the system to assign an ephemeral source port. Only the destination port needs to be a fixed port number.

Comment: You do not need both port 0 and 3000 which is giving the error.  I would start with Putty and see if you receive the messages in putty.  Also from cmd.exe>Netstat -a and see if another application is register to receive the port number.  It is possible another app is registered for the port so your app is not receiving the messages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UdpClient receive on broadcast address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746519/udpclient-receive-on-broadcast-address)